# Calculating Algorithm Efficiency and Complexity

Tags: performance, algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory, time-complexity

My instructor taught us how to calculate the computational complexity of an algorithm, but she only did so very briefly and not so well. More specifically, could someone help me calculate the computational complexity of the following:

```
        While (PLength > 0)
        chartest = sHex(i)
        ascvalue = Strings.Asc(chartest)
        decvalue = Convert.ToDecimal(ascvalue)
        shiftdecvalue = decvalue + 1
        asc = ChrW(shiftdecvalue)
        emptychararray(i) = asc
        i = i + 1
        PLength = PLength - 1
    End While
```

They way I've thought about it, it just comes out to be T(n)= C_1*n+C_2*(n-1)+C_3*(n-1)+C_4*(n-1)+C_5*(n-1)+C_6*(n-1)+C_7*(n-1)+C_8*(n-1)+C_9*(n-1)+C_10*(n-1)

But I feel like I might be oversimplifying it. Furthermore, how do I get the big O notation for this? I've been looking online for resources on how to teach myself this, so if you have any recommendations, those would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where do you get that many terms from? You're supposed to write it as `T(n) = something containing T(n-c) or T(n/c) for some c`. Look at some other examples of recurrence relations and what you should do should become clear. Similarly you should be able to find plenty of examples of converting recurrence relations to big-O notation. Also, you'll need to tell us the complexity of `sHex`, `Strings.Asc`, `Convert.ToDecimal` and `ChrW` in relation to `i`.

Comment: The way my professor taught it is that every line of code that completes some operations is given a constant and then multiplied by the number of times the operation is performed. So what I was thinking in my case is that every line is complete n-1 times (since n depends on the number of times the while loop is performed). The complexity of the items you asked about are assumed as a 1 step operation (so I think they would be of order n).

Answer (score 0):

First note that T(n) can be rewritten as `T(n) = C1 * n + C2`.  Then note that big O notation ignores constants, so the complexity is `O(n)`.

Comment: You really should explain how you got to `T(n) = C1 * n + C2`. If you want to do other people's homework, you should at least attempt to explain it in enough detail so they're able to figure out the next problem of this type they're faced with.

Comment: @Dukeling I was waiting for a response from the OP.  When assisting people in understanding new concepts, it helps to have a dialog, so as to discover the particular points that are the source of confusion. So I bisected the problem, the first half being the conversion from the OP's statement of T(n) to the simplified T(n), the second half being the conversion from the simplified T(n) to big-O notation.

Comment: That might be a good way to help OP with minimal effort on your part, but, in terms of long-term value to others, I feel it's better to explain in sufficient detail for presumably just about anyone to understand right off the bat, then to modify your answer to clarify any points which OP might have a problem with. Also, given the expression OP came up with, I **strongly** doubt he/she will be able to understand how you came up your expression.

Comment: @Dukeling The conversion from OP's expression to mine is simple algebra, since for example, `C_2*(n-1)` can be rewritten as `C_2 * n + (-C_2)` and likewise for all of the other terms in OPs expression.